# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB with Java. This is my code

```
    MongoCredential mongoCredential;
    mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(<uname>, <dbname>, <password>);
    List<ServerAddress> list = Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));

    MongoClientSettings.Builder mongoClientSettingsBuilder = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .credential(mongoCredential)
            .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder.hosts(list));

    MongoClientSettings settings = mongoClientSettingsBuilder.build();
```

Executing this I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(Lcom/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ServerSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Ljava/util/List;Lcom/mongodb/event/CommandListener;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mongodb/MongoDriverInformation;Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/mongodb/connection/Cluster;
```

I do not know what is the reason for this. Can someone help me out with this

Comment: Did you loaded the MongoDB Java Driver?
And which version did you loaded?
Did you added it to your classpath?

Comment: Yes I have loaded the driver. I am using mongodb-driver-3.6.4

Comment: Maybe try with an update to 4.0.1

Comment: Ok will try. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the driver version to 3.12.2, it worked. Thank you @Yonngan

Comment: @Jackson Not worked for me. could you please add pom.xml ?

Comment: For me it worked for org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-driver_2.11:2.9.0

Answer (score 4):

This may be a conflict and confusion caused by several mongodb-driver jar file that system detected. I just solve the similar problem--`NoSuchMethodError` with disabling mongodb-driver-sync and using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb in pom.xml like the following one:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.2.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

Comment: If you have no `mongodb-driver-sync` which dependency provides you `MongoClient`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mongodb-driver in your sbt file. In my case, it was

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "4.5.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "3.0.1"
```

Remove `mongo-scala-driver` dependency such that final build will look like this

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "3.0.1"
```